# Two tableviews in one view controller, one table view not showing up

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have two `TableView`s in one `ViewController` and only one table is able to populate. I have created outlets for both tables in my view controller. Here is my `viewDidLoad`

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerTableView.delegate = self
    pickerTableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    pickerTableView.reloadData()
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

It seems that the only table that is read is `self.tableView` and the `pickerTableView` is never read in the protocols for `UITableView`

```
extension MealViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        let nameHeaderView = NameHeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
        nameHeaderView.delegate = self
        nameHeaderView.sectionIndex = section
        nameHeaderView.nameButton.setTitle(Data.userModels[section].name, for: .normal)
        return nameHeaderView
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        return Data.userModels.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        if Data.userModels[section].isExpandable {
            return Data.userModels[section].itemModels.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    } else if tableView == pickerTableView {
        return Data.userModels.count
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCells", for: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell
        cell.setup(itemModel: Data.userModels[indexPath.section].itemModels[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    } else if tableView == pickerTableView {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pickerCells", for: indexPath) as! NamePickerTableViewCell
        cell2.setup(userModel: Data.userModels[indexPath.row])
        print(Data.userModels)
        return cell2
    }
    else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

}

I have also applied constraints on each `tableView` so they both appear on the screen. When I run the app, the data for `self.tableView` is shown however the `pickerTableView` appears empty. `self.tableView` requires sections and `pickerTableView` does not require sections, could this be an issue? Also there is data in the `Data.userModels` array.

And just for reference, here is my `UITableViewCell` class:

```
class NamePickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var namePickerLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func setup(userModel: UserModel) {
    namePickerLabel.text = userModel.name
}
```

}

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need any section in pickerTableView, then also it has to have at least one section.

So `return 1` in method `numberOfSections` when `tableview == self. pickerTableView`.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        return Data.userModels.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```